# c++ late instantiation of global variable

Tags: c++, c++11

I have code where a global resource has to be set up by quite some code:

```
globalClass foo;  // global variable / object; give it a memory space to live

void doSomething( void )
{
  foo.bar();      // use the global foo object
}

int main( int argc, const char *argv[] )
{
  foo( argc );   // foo can only be instantiated in main as it's using
                 // information that's only available here

  doSomething(); // use the global foo object

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, `foo` is of global scope - but to call its constructor I need some information that's only available inside of `main`.

**How can I achieve that?**

The only solution I could figure out is to make `foo` a pointer to `globalClass` - but that would result in a pointer dereferencing each time I'm using `foo`. This might create a performance problem when used in a tight loop...

PS: In the real program `main` and `doSomething` would live in different files. And it's of course guaranteed that `foo` won't be accessed before it's instantiated.

Comment: Would making it a global function that returns a reference to a static local be that much syntatic burden? If so, if you're already comfortable living with the "evil" of globals, why not endure one more evil and just give `globalClass` an `init` function rather than relying on the constructor?

Comment: Why does it have to be a global variable, and not a parameter to `doSomething`?

Comment: Syntactic burden is ok for me, as long as it stays at compile time or perhaps setup time (i.e. the first iteration during runtime). The `init` idea is good but I'm sorry that I forgot to note that `globalClass` is from an external library that I'm not eager to modify. (BTW: sure, globals are considered evil - but in a controlled environment like here for me a good choice over storing a copy of `globalClass` in each instance `doSomething` which is in reality a method of a class...)

Comment: Globals are only evil if not properly coded. But if you want to avoid them, you can create and initialize the object in `main` and pass pointers/references to it around to all functions that need to access it.

Comment: You can't call `foo`'s constructor. You can call `globalClass`'s constructor to make an instance of it. In your `main`, you are calling `globalClass::operator()` in `foo`, which is a `globalClass` instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about having `foo` as a `static` variable inside a function? That way, it only gets instantiated when the function is called:

```
globalClass& getThing()
{
  static globalClass thing;
  return thing;
}

void doSomething(const globalClass& thing);

int main()
{
  const globalClass& x = getThing();
  doSomething(x);  
}
```

Comment: +1, this method also protects against the [Static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use.html)

Comment: I work with heavily threaded code.  We do not use function static because there is no guarantee if two threads enter the function at the same time the function static only gets constructed once.

Comment: @Brian I think there is that guarantee. But if you want tobe sure, start the threads from nmain after the object has been constructed, and pass it around.

Comment: This is awkward, though, because you need the object to be default-construcible *and* assignable...

Comment: @kerreksb that is clear. But default constructible us already a requirement in OP's example. The assignable requirement could be removed by using a reference. I realise the whole thing ain't pretty though.

Comment: This example doesn't show how `globalClass` is initialized by `argc` in `main` like the OP asks, and a const reference will not let you do that either.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Where would that guarantee come from?

Comment: @AndersJohansson there is nothing in OP's post that says the `globalClass` object is "initialized" by `argc` in `main`. OP's code is calling `operator()` on a `globalClass` on an existing instance. I cannot provide a better solution without more information.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the guarantee comes from `6.7 [stmt.dcl]`, unfortunately it only seems to apply to C++11.

Comment: The old C++ standard said function static could be constructed the first time the function is called.  If two threads call it the first time at the same time, trouble ensued.  For the new standard to make that guarantee, means either (a) function static are ctord along with globals or (b) there is a mutex to protect the first call.

Comment: @brianbeuning it doesn't have to mean either thing. The standard just mandates what has to happen, not how it is implemented. But lazy initialization is still there (otherwise a lot of code would break).

Answer (score 6):

Using a pointer as you mentioned is the simplest and cleanest thing to do.  The overhead of a pointer dereference isn't really that much.  I'd recommend using this unless you've really demonstrated that the overhead is noticeable.

Your second option would be to separate out the construction and the initialization of `globalClass` into two separate methods.  The constructor would do only the simplest things that required no external information, and you'd call `init(argc)` or whatever inside `main` to incorporate the external info.

You could also use an assignment to initialize foo, like:

```
globalClass foo;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    globalClass bar(argc);
    foo = bar;
}
```

which is essentially using a temporary variable to do the initialization, then copying over the result.

Comment: Nice solution, but sometimes it won't work: you'd need a default constructor and the assignment operator (or an copy operator). If `globalClass` doesn't have those it won't work.  
But for many cases that's a good solution that's only giving a bit of overhead during setup time but is free during run time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really terrible hack if you don't want the indirection and don't mind doing the cleanup yourself:

```
union ClassHolder
{
    globalClass x;
    char buf[sizeof globalClass];

    constexpr ClassHolder() noexcept : buf() { }
};

ClassHolder h;
globalClass & foo = h.x;

int main()
{
    new (static_cast<void *>(&h.x)) globalClass(arg1, arg2, arg3);

    // main program

    h.x.~globalClass();
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I would like to term this the "union hack" :-)

Comment: There you go :P Though actually I wonder whether the initialisation of `buf` counts as a write...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That wouldn't matter, because we overwrite it later.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Hey, isn't there a clause that the pointer to any union member is the same? Maybe my original version was fine...

Comment: No, because you're _still_ writing to `buf` then reading from `x`. Maybe.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like ths:

```
globalClass* foo;  
// declare foo as a global pointer to class globalClass. No object instantiated here
    
    void doSomething( void )
    {
      foo->bar();      // use the global foo object pointer
    }
    
    int main( int argc, const char *argv[] )
    {
      foo = new globalClass(); 
      // an object is instantiated from class globalClass and the pointer to that object assigned to foo. This object will not be destroyed when the function who created ends. Parameters for the constructor can the passed inside the ()
    
      doSomething(); // use the global foo object
    
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It seems you didn't read the question. This obvious solution using a pointer was explicitly excluded to avoid the pointer lookup.